# Посчитайте сумму элементов последовательности Фибоначчи в python

Tags: python, числа-фибоначчи

Нужно посчитать сумму из кода ниже. А так же минимум и максимум. Никак не могу понять. Получаются неправильные ответы. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
a = 0
b = 1

N = 30

print(a)
print(b)

for i in range(1, N-2):
    c = a
    a = b
    b = a + c

    if b % 2 == 0:
        print(-(b ** 2))
    else:
        print(b)
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос писание суммы, которую нужно сосчитать.

Comment: 0
1
1
-4
3
5
-64
13
21
-1156
55
89
-20736
233
377
-372100
987
1597
-6677056
4181
6765
-119814916
17711
28657
-2149991424
75025
121393
-38580030724
317811

Answer (score 2):

Фактически здесь имеется некая последовательность на базе чисел Фибоначчи, поэтому известная формула суммы не подходит, так как чётные числа "превращаются" в отрицательные квадраты.

```py
a = 0
b = 1
N = 30

min = 9E99
max = -9E99
sum = 0

for i in range(1, N-2):
    c = a
    a = b
    b = a + c
    
    f = - b * b if b % 2 == 0 else b
    
    sum += f
    if f < min: min = f
    if f > max: max = f

print(f"sum = {sum}, min = {min}, max={max}")
```

```
sum = -40856333256, min = -38580030724, max=317811
```

Answer (score 1):

какой-то странный код

во первых сумма `N` чисел Фибоначчи равно `F(n+2) - 1`, не похоже, что вы вычисляете именно его

вот тут вывод в зависимости от чётности числа - зачем?

```
if b % 2 == 0:
    print(-(b ** 2))
else:
    print(b)
```

определение минимума и максимума вообще нет

да и какой смысл минимума и максимума, если числа Фибоначчи всегда возрастают, поэтому самое большое - самое последнее, а самое маленькое - самое первое :)

Comment: В задаче даны именно такие условия, исходя из них и нужно найти сумму, а так же минимальное и максимальное значения

Comment: код модифицировать можно?

Comment: Да. как раз нужно модифицировать, чтобы найти решения

Comment: я в самом начале написал как его надо модифицировать - считать до `n + 2`, `print` выкинуть на помойку, в данном коде просто показано как считается число Фибоначчи, остальное - мусор

Comment: Посчитать нужно именно из полученных значений

Comment: подсчитать сумму `N` членов последовательности зная `N - 3` значения? а также вычислить N-ый член (максимальный элемент) зная `N-3` - а какая математика для этого нужна? формулу какую использовать?

Answer (score 0):

Заводите глобальную переменную summa=0
и еще парочку:
min=9e99
max=-9e99

после этого внутри цикла работаете с этими переменными (складываете что нужно, сравниваете и т.п.).

В конце работы (после цикла) печатаете результат.

```
for i in range(1, N-2):
  c = a
  a = b
  b = a + c
  sum = sum + b
  if b<min: min=b
  if b>max: max=b
print(f"min={min} max={max} sum={sum}")
```

это если b это нужные нам числа

Comment: А можно немного подробнее, а то уже голову сломал? Не понимаю как найти не в списке мин и макс